# How to zip specific files that are located in subdirectories

Tags: command-line, ssh, zip

I have a directory that consists of many subdirectories, and each subdirectory contains different files such as:

Directory `All` contains subdirectories `A, B, C, and D`. Each subdirectory contains files such as:

```
A (Run1.csv, Run4.csv)
B (Run2.csv, Run3.csv)
C (Run1.csv, Run3.csv)
D (Run2.csv, Run4.csv)
```

As you can see, each file has different duplicates in different subdirectories. For example, `Run1.csv` in folder `A` has different data from `Run1.csv` in folder `C`.

What I want to do is that I want to zip a specific run file, for example, I want to zip all the files of run2. I used the following commands:

```
zip run2.zip All Run2.csv 

zip run2.zip Run2.csv
```

But none of them works.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `bash` Pathname Expansion as follows:

```bsh
zip run2.zip */Run2.csv
```

`*/Run2.csv` matches every file called `Run2.csv` in any subdirectory. If you have *very* many files that match the glob, this fails because of the shell’s `ARG_MAX` limit. To work around that, use:

```bsh
printf '%s\0' */Run2.csv | xargs -0 zip run2.zip
```

This uses the builtin `printf` to build up a zero-delimited list of the matching files and pipes it to `xargs`, which calls `zip` as often as necessary. As `add` is `zip`’s default mode, it updates the archive adding the files to it.

If you need to dig further into an unknown or changing number of subdirectories, set `bash`’s `globstar` option with

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
```

and use:

```bsh
zip run2.zip **/Run2.csv  # or respectively
printf '%s\0' **/Run2.csv | xargs -0 zip run2.zip
```

`**/Run2.csv` matches every file called `Run2.csv` in any subdirectory recursively.

#### Further reading

- [`man zip`/PATTERN MATCHING](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zip.1.html#pattern%20matching)
- [`man bash`/EXPANSION/Pathname Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion)
- [Bash Hackers Wiki: Pathname expansion (globbing)](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)
- [TLDP Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 18.2. Globbing](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

Comment: If youre digging further, find might be a good option

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes, but I left that to Romeo Ninov for [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134058/507051) and helped him build the `find` command line. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like to search and archive all (for example) `Run2.csv` files:

```
zip run2.zip `find . -name Run2.csv`
```

By suggestion if OP expect special characters (like space) in file/directories names can use command like:

```
find . -name Run2.csv -exec zip run2.zip {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for finding files and zip them in separate files :

```
find . -name Run2.csv -print | zip Run2.zip -@
```

Comment: This fails if any of the file or directory names contain whitespaces, you could use `… -print0 | xargs -0 zip Run2.zip` instead.